# Exclude a certain element from css rule

Tags: css, wordpress

First time post, bit of a n00b...

Working on a WordPress site for a client. The following piece of CSS is used to style all hyperlinks within the post_content section of a page a dark blue color (#2a5db0).

```
section.post_content a {
    color: #2a5db0;
}

a:hover {
    color: #2a5db0;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

However, buttons on the site are also styled to a dark blue color, making any button hyperlinks almost unreadable.

Essentially I want to exclude any hyperlinks enclosed within `<button>` tags from the above rule. What piece of CSS can I write to ensure that hyperlink text on buttons is displayed in white (#fff) but all other hyperlinks within the post_content section are styled #2a5db0 as per the above rule?

Thanks!

Comment: Use inline css to override the css file

Comment: I'm not sure why you are using links inside button? Its better to use only one. Either use `<button>` or `<a>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though slow, this should work:

```
section.post_content *:not(button) > a {
    color: #2a5db0;
}
```

But your last paragraph seems to suggest that you want this:

```
section.post_content a {
    color: #2a5db0;
}
section.post_content button > a {
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Second solution works perfectly, thanks for your help!

Comment: @Dan If this helped you, please click the checkmark on the left to mark this answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can target hyperlinks within a button tag like so:

This will target links within a button tag:

```
section.post_content button > a {
   color: #fff;
}
```

Or

This will target the button text colour:

```
section.post_content button {
   color: #fff;
}
```